# Getting HTTP response as a java object

Tags: java, json, spring, http

I am using Spring Web to create a rest resource. I have created Document objects in Java similar to the Json response. When I use String.class as the response type, I get the response from the request. When I change the response to the class I have created the boy is null.

Here is my HttpGettter

```
   private <T> T perform(String token, String resourcePath, Class<T> responseType, HttpMethod method, MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams) {
     UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
          .scheme(protocol)
          .host(host);

    UriComponents uriComponents = uriComponentsBuilder.build();
    String url = uriComponents.toString();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("contentType","application/json");

    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<T> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, method, requestEntity, responseType);
    return responseEntity.getBody();
   }
     return null;
 }
```

**Json Document**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)
public class SiteDocument {

  @JsonProperty("id")
  private int siteID;
  @JsonProperty("site_name")
  private String siteName;
  @JsonProperty("url")
  private String url;
}
```

Function call

```
 perform(null, "/sites", SiteDocument[].class, HTTP.get,null)
```

**JSON Response**

```
{  
 "items":[  
  {  
     "id":5841970702,
     "site_name":"test",
     "url":"http://sample/again/",
     "pages":2,
     "policies":0,
     "product":[  
        "quality_assurance",
        "accessibility",
        "seo",
        "policy"
     ],
     "_links":{  
        "site":{  
           "href":"https://api.siteimprove.com/v2/sites/5841970702"
        }
     }
  },

  {  
     "id":5881398958,
     "site_name":"preview.site",
     "url":"http://sample.site",
     "pages":0,
     "policies":0,
     "product":[  
        "quality_assurance",
        "policy"
     ],
     "_links":{  
        "site":{  
           "href":"https://api.siteimprove.com/v2/sites/5881398958"
        }
     }
  }
 ],
 "total_items":5,
 "total_pages":1,
  "links":{  
  "self":{  
     "href":"https://api.siteimprove.com/v2/sites"
  }
  }
  }
```

Ignore the incorrect formatting of the JSON response. Edited to make it short.

**Exception**

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract
>   response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type
>   [class
>   [Lcom.blueprint.siteimprove.webresources.documents.SiteDocument;]
>   and content type [text/html]

**Updated exception**

> Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for
>   response type [class
>   [Lcom.coremedia.blueprint.siteimprove.webresources.documents.SiteDocument;]
>   and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]

Added on headers the foollowing

```
  headers.add("Accept","application/json");
  headers.add("Content-Type","application/json");
```

Comment: From the exception it looks like thre response format is text/html and spring cannot find a suitable converter for this. Try setting accept header as "application/json" in your request

Comment: On the first look it is the headers.add("contentType", "...") change it to headers.add("Content-Type", "...")

Comment: @uday: i already tried that. I get the same error for that as well.

Comment: Can you post the Controller code. It should be annotated with @RestController or by any other WS and should be configured to produce JSON.

Comment: @pvpkiran: Now having that added in the header, content-type is changed to application/json

Comment: @uday: i do not have the controller annotated as `@RestController`..

Comment: Why is there return null in the HttpGetter class? And if you only want the method to behave RestFul, you can add `@ResponseBody` annotation before the method.

Comment: @AayushKumarSingha: The null is the parameter on the function definition. it has nothing to do with the response entitiy. The token paramter is null.

Comment: `return responseEntity.getBody();` after this line, the method `perform` ends?

Comment: The problem was that the jackson runtime dependency was not added.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the POM file. the runtime dependency was not added in the POM file. The following dependencies are to be added in the POM file.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```